# Laravel Eloquent Relation vs Database Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I'm working on a Laravel project. I usually get database relations through Eloquent ORM, like belongsToMany or hasOne and such. But when you get data from these kind of relations, does it run an extra query? Is there a performance difference between:

```
$this->hasOne(Model::class)
```

and

```
Model::find($this->some_id)
```

? Thank you very much.

Comment: You could install `laravel debugbar` and see how it performs in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you some example. I hope this can help you.

I have 2 models:

In A model:

```
  public $fillable = [
        'id',
        ...
    ];
public function b()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(B::class, 'a_id', 'id');
    }
```

In B model:

```
  public $fillable = [
        'id',
        'a_id',
        ...
    ];
public function a()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(A::class, 'a_id', 'id');
    }
```

Then you can get data like that:

```
$a = A::find($id);
$b = B::find($a->b->id);
echo $a->attributeOfA;
echo $b->attributeOfB;
echo $a->b->attributeOfB;
echo $b->a->attributeOfA;
```

use **Laravel Debugbar** or **dd();** to test it